# How to handle CopyToDataTable() when no rows?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the code:

```
dt = collListItems.GetDataTable().AsEnumerable()
        .Where(a => Convert.ToString(a["Expertise"]).Contains(expertise) && Convert.ToString(a["Office"]) == office)
         .CopyToDataTable(); 

filteredCount = dt.Rows.Count();
```

How should I best handle the event when there are no rows that match? Currently I get

> The source contains no DataRows

but I want to set filteredCount to 0 in that case.

I know a try-catch works, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Is `GetDataTable()` expensive (calls database, web service, etc.)? Are you interested in *just* the count or do you need the data as well?

Comment: It's not expensive, it will be maximum 70-90 rows and not used oftern, I need both the data (if there is any) and count. It works fine if there is at least one row left after the filtering

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You certainly do not want to use a try/catch for this. Try/Catch should be used in truly exceptional circumstances, you do not want to have it drive your control flow. In nearly all situations, there are better methods that are built right into the language/library or require minimal effort to code.

In this case, you want to capture the table beforehand so that you do not invoke the `GetDataTable()` method more times than necessary, because we're going to need it if the query does not include any results. You could also optionally include `ToList()` on the query if the query itself is expensive or long-running, so you only need to do that once.

Afterwards, it's a matter of testing if there are *any* rows in the result. If so, you can safely copy to a datatable. Otherwise, just clone the structure of the *original* table (will not include the rows), so that in either case, you have a proper table structure and can inspect the row count, bind it to a control, etc., and there are no surprises.

```
var table = collListItems.GetDataTable();    
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(...); // optionally include .ToList();
var dt = rows.Any() ? rows.CopyToDataTable() : table.Clone();
int filteredCount = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this solution :

```
            DataRow[] filtered_rows = data.Tables[0].Select(filter_string);

            if(filtered_rows.Length > 0)
            {
                filtered_data = filtered_rows.CopyToDataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                filtered_data.Clear();
            }
```

`data.Tables[0]` is the source table and `filtered_data` is the resultant table.

Answer (score 0):

you can first judge whether there are rows that match:

```
var rows = collListItems.GetDataTable().AsEnumerable()
        .Where(a => Convert.ToString(a["Expertise"]).Contains(expertise) && Convert.ToString(a["Office"]) == office);
DataTable dt = table.Clone();
if (rows.Count() > 0)
    dt = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a simpler solution:

```
var Adj = (from c in View.AdjustmentsDataSource.AsEnumerable()
            where c["Adjustment"] != System.DBNull.Value
            select c);

if (Adj == null || Adj.Count() == 0)
     return;

DataTable dtChanges = Adj.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Your return statement suggestions non-deterministic coding style which can get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from myRow in dtL1Users.AsEnumerable()
                                          where (Convert.ToInt32(myRow["No_x0020_of_x0020_L1_x0020_Remin"]) >= Convert.ToInt32(maxL1Escalation) && Convert.ToDateTime(myRow["L2_x0020_Last_x0020_Escalated_x0"]) < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(reminderinterval)))
                                          select myRow;

                            foreach (var v in results)
                            {
                                collEligible = results.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
                                break;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me. please try

```
 DataRow []dataRow = dataTable.Select(query, seq);
 if (dataRow != null && dataRow.Length > 0)
 {
     return dataTable.Select(query, seq).CopyToDataTable();                                            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable generic solution:

Create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => source.Count() > 0 ? source : null;
```

Now you can call this extension method like:

```
var newTable = dataRows.NullIfEmpty()?.CopyToDataTable();
//Here dataRows can be of any IEnumerable collection such as EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> in case of DataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method Any(): to check before using CopyToDataTable() to avoid No Datarow found exception

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> result = <<Some Linq Query>>;

        if (result.Any())
        {
             
        }
```