# compare datatables and save unmatched rows in third datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I am trying to compare two datatables and capture the difference in third datatable.

```
DataTable one = new DataTable();
one.Columns.Add("ID");
one.Columns.Add("PCT");
one.Rows.Add("1", "0.1");
one.Rows.Add("2", "0.2");
one.Rows.Add("3", "0.3");
DataTable two = new DataTable();
two.Columns.Add("ID");
two.Columns.Add("PCT");
two.Columns.Add("OldPCT");
two.Rows.Add("1", "0.1", "0");
two.Rows.Add("2", "0.1", "0");
two.Rows.Add("3", "0.9", "0");
two.Columns.Remove("OldPCT");

//First method
DataTable three = two.AsEnumerable().Except(one.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
foreach (DataRow dr in three.AsEnumerable())
{
    string strID = dr[0].ToString();
    string strPCT = dr[1].ToString();
}

//second method
var diffName = two.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("PCT")).Except(one.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("PCT")));
if (diffName.Any())
{
    DataTable Table3 = (from row in two.AsEnumerable()
                        join name in diffName
                        on row.Field<string>("PCT") equals name
                        select row).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

So far I have tried two methods and I'm not not getting my expected result and it should be like.

In third datatable the values should be like mentioned below.

```
 ID    PCT
 2     O.1
 3     0.9
```

Recent One:

```
DataTable one = new DataTable();
one.Columns.Add("ID");
one.Columns.Add("PCT");
one.Rows.Add("1", "0.1");
one.Rows.Add("2", "0.2");
one.Rows.Add("2", "0.2");
one.Rows.Add("3", "0.3");
one.Rows.Add("3", "0.3");
DataTable two = new DataTable();
two.Columns.Add("ID");
two.Columns.Add("PCT");
two.Rows.Add("1", "0.1");
two.Rows.Add("2", "0.1");
two.Rows.Add("2", "0.1");
two.Rows.Add("3", "0.8");
two.Rows.Add("3", "0.9");
```

Now I need to get all the rows from datatable two except first row. But I am getting only last three rows.

Comment: Keep in mind, `DataTable` has a `GetChanges()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Just merge the tables, then call `GetChanges()` and it will return you a third `DataTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Hogan's answer, you can use `DataRowComparer.Default` as the second parameter to the `Except()` method (instead of creating a custom IEqualityComparer):

```
// this will get all rows from table two that don't match rows in one
// the result is an IEnumerable<DataRow> 
var unmatched = two.AsEnumerable()
  .Except(one.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);

// CopyToDataTable converts an IEnumerable<DataRow> into a DataTable
// but it blows up if the source object is empty

// this statement makes sure unmatched has data before calling CopyToDataTable()
// if it is empty, we 'clone' (make an empty copy) of one of the original DataTables
var three = unmatched.Any() ? unmatched.CopyToDataTable() : one.Clone();
```

This will do a value-based comparison of the fields in each row to determine if they are equal.

Comment: If the result is 0 means if there is no change, I am getting this error `The source contains no DataRows.`. How can I handle this?

Comment: That's probably coming from the CopyToDataTable() method. Check this post for how to deal with it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815916/how-to-handle-copytodatatable-when-no-rows

Comment: I am very new to .net and I'm not good enough to understand this, so can you please help me solve this. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my example with code to handle the case where there are no changes. I also  added a bunch of comments to explain what's going on.

Comment: I don't think default works because he only wants to Check two of the fields

Comment: @Hogan - Once the "OldPCT" column gets removed - `two.Columns.Remove("OldPCT");` - the two tables have the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom IEqualityComparer

```
void Main()
{
   DataTable one = new DataTable();
   one.Columns.Add("ID");
   one.Columns.Add("PCT");
   one.Rows.Add("1", "0.1");
   one.Rows.Add("2", "0.2");
   one.Rows.Add("3", "0.3");
   DataTable two = new DataTable();
   two.Columns.Add("ID");
   two.Columns.Add("PCT");
   two.Columns.Add("OldPCT");
   two.Rows.Add("1", "0.1", "0");
   two.Rows.Add("2", "0.1", "0");
   two.Rows.Add("3", "0.9", "0");
   two.Columns.Remove("OldP

   DataTable three = two.AsEnumerable().Except(one.AsEnumerable(),new RowEqualityComparer()).CopyToDataTable();
   foreach (DataRow dr in three.AsEnumerable())
   {
       string strID = dr[0].ToString();
       string strPCT = dr[1].ToString();
   }
}


class RowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
   public bool Equals(DataRow b1, DataRow b2)
   {
     if ((b1.Field<string>("ID") == b2.Field<string>("ID")) && (b1.Field<string>("PCT") == b2.Field<string>("PCT")))
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
   }

   public int GetHashCode(DataRow bx)
   {
     return (bx.Field<string>("ID")+bx.Field<string>("PCT")).GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Comment: If the result is 0 means if there is no change, I am getting this error The source contains no DataRows.. How can I handle this?

Comment: Add an if statement I guess